# How to have Solr autocomplete on whole phrase - solr

Tags: xml, solr

I'm creating suggest like google. for now, when i write "do", solr returns "dog", "doll", it returns only one word on schema field.
What i want is if it return whole field like "doggy blah blah", "dog store" etc, that would be nice.
here's my schema.xml

```
<field name = "companyDisplayName" type = "text_auto" multiValued="false" indexed = "true" stored = "false" />
```

and my schema fieldtype configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" ><analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="1"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here's my solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
   <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_auto</str>
      <str name="field">companyDisplayName</str>
   </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="fl">companyDisplayName</str>
<str name="qf">companyDisplayName^30</str>
<str name="pf">companyDisplayName^50.0</str>
<str name="group">true</str>
<str name="group.field">companyDisplayName</str>
<str name="sort">score desc</str>
<str name="group.sort">score desc</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
```

and my query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/vw_search_company_with_buildings/suggest?spellcheck.q=hunn
```

Answer (score 0):

There multiple changes you need to make for your suggester to get working.

> Use **stored=true** for the filed you want to use in suggestion. I would suggest you to copy the field in another field using `copyField` tag. You need not to index the copied field. You can replace the `text_general` definition in your `schema.xml`. It is same as default, but a simpler version.

```
<field name = "suggest_field" type = "text_general" multiValued="false" indexed = "false" stored = "true" />

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

> Now use the following configuration for suggester `searchComponent` and `requestHandler`. This configuration uses `solr.SuggestComponent` instead of `solr.SpellCheckComponent`. For `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` default highlighting is `true`, here it is `false`. I have added `<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>` for getting the complete attribute value in the suggester.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">suggest_field</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>


<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">5</str>
    <str name="suggest.collate">false</str>
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    <str name="fl">suggest_field</str>
    <str name="qf">suggest_field^30</str>
    <str name="pf">suggest_field^50.0</str>
    <str name="group">true</str>
    <str name="group.field">suggest_field</str>
    <str name="sort">score desc</str>
    <str name="group.sort">score desc</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

> Use the following command to make the suggestion requests. This contains `suggest.build=true` in the url, which mean it will build the dictionary every time you make request. You can remove it for your production purpose.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/vw_search_company_with_buildings/suggest?suggest.build=true&suggest.q=do
```

**PS :** There is issue with `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` that, it lock the suggestion dictionary directory when you reload it second time. You can use `indexPath` for solving the issue.

Here is the [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662808/2254048).