# Search API autocomplete with SolR: How to return the full field with autocomplete

Tags: drupal, solr, autocomplete

I'm using Drupal 7 and have a simple view built using search_api, search_api_solr, and search_api_autocomplete.

The view displays all nodes of type "person". The title field is exposed, and has the autocomplete feature.

It all works fine, except that I cannot seem to get the autocomplete feature to return the full title field.

For example, if I type "joh", I get the following suggestions: "John", "Johnson", "Johan".
They are correct, but I would like to get the full title field, e.g: "Dr John Smith", "Mr Johnson Mark", "Mrs Johan Alexander".

I have had a look at the various support issues or threads online, but could not find information about this.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide you suggester configuration?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32626428/2254048.